# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty ke^{-\sqrt{k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I've tried ratio test and it was inconclusive. I think comparison test would work with $\frac {k}{e^\sqrt{k}} \le \frac {k}{k^3}=\frac {1}{k^2}$ since $e^\sqrt k \ge k^3$ for large enough k. But I couldn't prove that inequality with induction. Can you help me prove that inequality or give me another way to show the convergence?

Thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: Do you know how to show $\frac{e^x}{x^{3/2}} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: @angryavian I think so, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show that the inequality $e^\sqrt k \ge k^3$, that is $\frac{k^3}{e^\sqrt{k}}\leq 1$, holds eventually. This follows from the fact that
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{k^3}{e^\sqrt{k}}=0<1.$$
Actually $\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{k^a}{e^{k^b}}=0$ for any positive numbers $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 4):

$e^{\sqrt k} \geq \frac {(\sqrt k)^{4}} {4!}$. Hence $\frac k {e^{\sqrt k}} \leq \frac {24} {k^{2}}$.

Comment: Does that come from the expansion of the $e^\sqrt k$, if so I don't know it yet. But still thanks for the help.